# fetch data from Oracle 11 DB using HQL to show it on a webpage

Tags: java, html, angularjs, hibernate, hql

All of my data for a particular Student is in a Student Table which has StudentId as the primary Key, i am able to get the data in List of StudentObject by using HQL (i am trying to get the list of students who are in say same class) but how should i make a Table on the front-end to display the details of all the students using HTML & AngularJS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you've exposed the serverside API that returns a list of student objects as Json string. you can use the $http service by angular:
as documented here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/someUrl'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

when receiving the response create a simple html table and loop through the students using ng-repeat on your  element:

```
<tr ng-repeat="student in studentList">
```

and in the td's u can use {{student.Name}} for example to fetch theuir names or any data you desire:

```
<td>{{student.Name}}</td>
```

hope I've helped, good luck :)